# How to ignore the next pdb-like breakpoints, including set_trace() calls?

Tags: python, pdb

I'm having the following issue:

I have code very much like the following

```
def my_function():
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    ....
```

During runtime, my function is called a lot of times. I'm interested in inspecting the code execution the first time this function is called.

If I'm done inspecting, I'd want to hit `c`, and have the normal execution of the program resume, without stopping at this break point the next times this function is called.

Is there a way to do this? Or must I do something completely different, like putting the `set_trace()` call some place that's only called once, and then once the breakpoint is hit, using a command like `tbreak my_function`, to set a one-time break point there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting an attribute of the function the first time it is executed. Something like:

```
def my_function():
    if not hasattr(my_function,'first_time'):
        my_function.first_time = 1 # Dummy value
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    ...
```

The attribute `first_time` will persist between function calls and the very first time the function is called, it will be created. Every next time the function is called, it will already exist and the code in the if statement will not be executed. This solution relies on your function not being a method inside a class since class methods can't have attributes, being that they're attributes of the class already.

Just as a note, I'm not sure if you have the import in your actual code, but best coding practices state you should put imports only at the beginning of your code, not inside functions as you have it.

Comment: haha, ok, I like this innocent hack :) I will totally use it.

Comment: Ignore pep8 style for debugging.  Put that import pdb  wherever it's convenient for you.  And use the semicolon :)   Unless, of course, you are delivering the code with a set_trace() per some requirement, then follow pep8.  I give you permission to break style for quick debugging.  Don't check it in and no one will ever know your sins.

Answer (score 1):

When I have this problem , I `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` at the beginning of the file (import time) or in `__main__` (run time)  then use the debugger `list` (or just `l`) command to find your line number and `break` (or just `b`) to set a breakpoint.

You can also launch the program in PDB mode from the start and get to the same point.

```
(Pdb) help break
b(reak) ([file:]lineno | function) [, condition]
With a line number argument, set a break there in the current
file.  With a function name, set a break at first executable line
of that function.  Without argument, list all breaks.  If a second
argument is present, it is a string specifying an expression
which must evaluate to true before the breakpoint is honored.

The line number may be prefixed with a filename and a colon,
to specify a breakpoint in another file (probably one that
hasn't been loaded yet).  The file is searched for on sys.path;
the .py suffix may be omitted.
```

I'll set a breakpoint at line 5, for example

```
(Pdb) b 5
Breakpoint 1 at /home/flipmcf/program.py:5
```

Now, continue

```
(Pdb) c
```

you will enter Pdb when the breakpoint is reached.

Since you only want to see the first run, simply remove the breakpoint

```
(Pdb) help clear
cl(ear) filename:lineno
cl(ear) [bpnumber [bpnumber...]]
With a space separated list of breakpoint numbers, clear
those breakpoints.  Without argument, clear all breaks (but
first ask confirmation).  With a filename:lineno argument,
clear all breaks at that line in that file.

Note that the argument is different from previous versions of
the debugger (in python distributions 1.5.1 and before) where
a linenumber was used instead of either filename:lineno or
breakpoint numbers.

(Pdb) clear 1
Deleted breakpoint 1
(Pdb) c
```